# Protocol Buffers In C#: How Are Boxed Value Types Handled

Tags: .net, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

In the following examples:

```
public class RowData
{
    public object[] Values;
}

public class FieldData
{
    public object Value;
}
```

I am curious as how either protobuf-net or dotnet-protobufs would handle such classes.  I am more familiar with protobuf-net, so what I actually have is:

```
[ProtoContract]
public class RowData
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public object[] Values;
}
[ProtoContract]
public class FieldData
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public object Value;
}
```

However I get an error saying "No suitable Default Object encoding found".  Is there an easy way to treat these classes, that I am just not aware of?

To elaborate more on the use case:

This is a scaled down version of a data class used in remoting.  So essentially it looks like this:

```
FieldData data = new FieldData();
data.Value = 8;

remoteObject.DoSomething(data);
```

Note: I've omitted the ISerializable implementation for simplicity, but it is as you'd expect.

Comment: OK - there's a way it can be done; t'is hacky, but it should work... update on the way...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(updated)

Right; figured it out... the main problem in my sample above was the value-getters; they were throwing exceptions. There were also some library glitches ([now fixed](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/downloads/)).

However, the simplest approach is `Nullable<T>` pass-thru properties:

```
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    private int? ValueInt32
    {
        get { return Get<int>(); }
        set { Value = value; }
    }
```

etc, with:

```
    private T? Get<T>() where T : struct
    {
        return (Value != null && Value is T) ? (T?)Value : (T?)null;
    }
```

Both this and the *Specified approach have been [tested](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/source/browse/trunk/Examples/ValueWrapper.cs), and now work fine.

Answer (score 6):

Re protobuf-net, which I maintain:

The issue here isn't value-types (which it will often handle fine) - it is the open `object` usage, which means it simply doesn't know what data to expect, and thus how to encode/decode it.

At the moment, I can't think of an easy/clean way to handle that. It will handle a range of common value-type scenarios, lists, and any level of hierarchy based on contracts (data-contract, proto-contracts, or some xml-schemas), but it needs a *clue*.

Perhaps if you can clarify the use-case, I might be able to help more? For example, the above wouldn't work very with `DataContractSerializer` or `XmlSerializer` either...

Re dotnet-protobufs; I can't really comment, but I'm pretty sure it would be even less forgiving; it is intended to be used with classes generated from a .proto file, so `object` would simply never enter into the model (Jon: correct me if I am wrong).

If you do leave more info, could you kindly post a comment here? So I can find it easily... Alternatively, drop me a mail directly (see my SO profile).

---

edit - here's the hacky thing I had in mind - it isn't working at the moment, but I'll figure out why tomorrow (probably). Note that in theory the extra members could all be private - I'm just trying to make it easy while debugging. Note that this doesn't take any extra storage. Like I say, it doesn't work today, but it should - I'll find out why...

```
[ProtoContract]
public class FieldData
{
    public object Value {get;set;}

    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public int ValueInt32 {
        get { return (int)Value; } set { Value = value; } }
    public bool ValueInt32Specified {
        get { return Value != null && Value is int; } set { } }

    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public float ValueSingle {
        get { return (float)Value; } set { Value = value; } }
    public bool ValueSingleSpecified {
        get { return Value != null && Value is float; } set { } }

    // etc for expected types
}
```

Comment: I can't comment on DataContractSerializer, but the XmlSerializer has no problem with this.

Comment: I was thinking more along the lines of inheritance.  I'll post what I had in mind.

Comment: @PatrickSzalapski did you have a specific scenario that isn't happy?

Comment: Just wondering if the "hacky thing you had in mind" could or should work.

Comment: @Patrick the dynamic type support offers some of this, but it isn't perfect for every scenario

Answer (score 0):

This is something like what I had in mind.  Let me know what you think.  Naturally I'd have to add a subclass for each value type I need to support.  What do you think?  Is there a better way, do you see any inefficiencies with this method?

```
[ProtoContract, Serializable]
[ProtoInclude(1, typeof(Int32FieldData))]
public abstract class FieldDataBase : ISerializable
{
    [ProtoIgnore]
    public abstract object Value { get; set;}
    protected FieldDataBase()
    { }

    #region ISerializable Members
    protected FieldDataBase(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        Serializer.Merge<FieldDataBase>(info, this);
    }
    public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        Serializer.Serialize<FieldDataBase>(info, this);
    }

    #endregion
}

[ProtoContract, Serializable]
public class Int32FieldData : FieldDataBase
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public int? Int32Value;

    [ProtoIgnore]
    public override object Value
    {
        get { return this.Int32Value.HasValue ? this.Int32Value : null; }
        set { this.Int32Value = (int?)value; }
    }
    public Int32FieldData() { }
    protected Int32FieldData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
        :base(info, context)
    { }
}
```

Comment: Hmm, looks like there may be an issue with nulls?

Comment: In which way "an issue"? Unfortunately, the wire-format has no concept of nulls, so the closest we can do is not transmit it - but either way, the inheritance should work. Are you getting a specific issue? (I've no time to try it right now...)

Comment: For info - due to the encoding details, direct encapsulation would be more efficient than inheritance (by 2-4 bytes per value).

Comment: well - the issue is, as you stated, nulls are not transmitted.  I'm working on a work around, but it's getting to be hacky^2 :-)

Comment: I guess I should point out, I had moved on to int?[] in which case I ended up serializing {1,2,3,4,null} and getting {1,2,3,4} back

Comment: So If I understand what you are saying additional properties cost no overhead if they are null.  So direct encapsulation would be much more efficient/straight forward.

Answer (score 0):

Direct encapsulation seems to work fine with no additional overhead from all the properties, in the following manner:

```
[ProtoContract, Serializable]
public class ObjectWrapper : ISerializable
{
    public ObjectWrapper()
    { }
    [ProtoIgnore]
    public object Value
    {
        get
        {
            if (Int32Value.HasValue)
                return Int32Value.Value;
            else if (BinaryValue != null)
                return BinaryValue;
            else
                return StringValue;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value is int)
                this.Int32Value = (int)value;
            else if (value is byte[])
                this.BinaryValue = (byte[])value;
            else if (value is string)
                this.StringValue = (string)value;
        }
    }
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    private int? Int32Value;
    [ProtoMember(2)]
    private string StringValue;
    [ProtoMember(3)]
    private byte[] BinaryValue;
            // etc

    #region ISerializable Members
    protected ObjectWrapper(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        Serializer.Merge<ObjectWrapper>(info, this);
    }
    public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        Serializer.Serialize<ObjectWrapper>(info, this);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: string and byte[] aren't really necessary in a general sense - I just know I will need them in my specific case